# Comma assignment (why right go first?) i.e. n,m = 1, 2?

Tags: ruby, fibonacci, operator-precedence

In the process of figuring out blocks and yields I came across these comma-separated assignments:

```
def fibit 
  n,m =1,1
  loop do |variable|
    yield n
    n,m = m,n+m # this line
    puts "n is #{n} m is #{m}"
  end 
end

fibit do |num|
  puts "Next : #{num}"
  break if num > 100
end
```

Why does the `m` get assigned first in this scenario?

Does the last one always go first? If so why?

This was also seen as only `e` has the value of 1 meaning `e` went first?

```
e,r=1
puts r
puts "-------"
puts e
```

Also, does anyone have an idea why the code-block versions just executes, where if I write the same code with no code block I actually need to call the method for it to run?

```
def fibit 
  n,m =1,1
  loop do |variable|
    puts "Next : #{n}"
    break if n > 100
    n,m = m,n+m
  end 
end
fibit
```

If I didn't have the last line it wouldn't run. Where in the first one I don't actually call the `fibit` method? Or is the block kicking it off?

Comment: what makes you think that `m` gets assigned first?

Comment: I fixed your question, but I think your shift key is broken as things that should have been capitalized were not.

Comment: thanks I'm on my laptop at a ruby class and sadly my typing is much worse when I don't have my split keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` does not get assigned first. When using multiple assignments, *all* right hand side calculations are done before *any* assignment to the left hand side.

That's how this code works:

```
a = 1
b = 3

a, b = b, a

a
# => 3
b
# => 1
```

This would not be possible if the assignment was done serially, since you would get that both would be either equal `1` or `3`.

To further prove my point, simply swap the assignment of `n` and `m` in your code, and you'll find that the result is the same:

```
def fibit 
n,m =1,1
loop do |variable|
    yield n
    m,n = n+m,m # this line
    puts "n is #{n} m is #{m}"
end 
end

fibit do |num|
    puts "Next : #{num}"
    break if num > 100
end
```

Comment: the first line of your answer was awesome and the example helped a great deal thanks Uri

Comment: do you have any idea why my code just runs using the block without calling the method? see the last edit i made

Comment: Because you _are_ calling the method with the block. You are doing `fibit() do |num|` but Ruby lets you drop the empty parentheses.